# How to kill Process by User?

Tags: vb.net, process, kill

I am using an application that kills the process `iexplore` (Internet Explorer) on a terminal server. The issue I am encountering is that I kill all processes of Internet Explorer on the terminal server, not just the one of the current user.

So if I log on as `User1` and kill IE, it will be killed for `User2`, `User3` and so on ... I only want `User1`'s Internet Explorer to be killed. I use the following code to kill my process:

```
Private Sub ClearProcesses(ByVal ProcessName As String)
    Dim myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)
    For Each Proc As Process In myProcesses
        Try
            Proc.Kill()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ClearProcess")
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to only kill the process for `User1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WMI to get the owner of a Process, and verify that the process is owned by the current user.

Using a Function like so:

```
Public Function GetProcessOwner(processId As Integer) As String
    Dim query As String = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
    Dim processList As ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()

    For Each obj As ManagementObject In processList
        Dim argList As String() = New String() {String.Empty, String.Empty}
        Dim returnVal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList))
        If returnVal = 0 Then
            ' argList(0) == User
            ' argList(1) == DOMAIN
            Return argList(0)
        End If
    Next

    Return "NO OWNER"
End Function
```

You should be able to do something like:

```
Private Sub ClearProcesses(ByVal ProcessName As String)
    Dim myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName).Where(Function(p) GetProcessOwner(p.Id) = currentUser)

    ' Your current code...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is ManagementObject a .NET or COM reference? I'm trying to find it

Comment: @Alex .NET - System.Management.dll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx

Comment: Thanks I it referenced now. I receive an error though: `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguements`. I used the following line of code:
`Dim myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName).Where(Sub(p) GetProcessOwner(p.Id) = System.Environment.UserName)`

Comment: Excellent. It works, thank you! There was another typo in the `GetProcessOwner` function. When declaring the query, my program crashed because I had to add `...Where ProcessID = " + processId.ToString`.